# Arduino UNO bricked?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, avrdude

How can I figure out, if an Arduino UNO is defect?
Have on, which I can't upload sketches to.
It's not working on Windows, even on Linux.

Everytime the following warning appears:

```
avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync
avrdude: stk500_loadaddr(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x18

avrdude: stk500_paged_load(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x98
avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync
avr_read(): error reading address 0x0000
    read operation not supported for memory "flash"
avrdude: failed to read all of flash memory, rc=-2
avrdude: stk500_disable(): protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0xe6
```

I don't have a clue of how to fix it.
The IDE's version is 1.8.8

Is the Arduino Bricked? Restarting both systems, the Arduino IDE and even Arduino (Reset) didn't help.

~ JackyTech

Comment: Had it ever worked before now?

Comment: Is it genuine or a Chinese clone?

Comment: It had worked over three years.
It's the original (dark blue) Arduino UNO.

Comment: When the serial port is detected by the computer but uploading is not possible, then you can try to burn the bootloader.

Comment: What did u selected in board menu?

Comment: I've burnt the bootloader on it and it works now. But now I've the same problem with an unrecognized Micro... Thanks for the advice mentioning the bootloader.